# paypal express checkout не работает с sandbox

Tags: php, paypal

я интегрирую оплату с paypal express checkout по примеру https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

скачал все нужные файлы, но у меня не получается выполнять тестовые покупки. не переадресует в paypal, а выдает ошибку. "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Error Message: Error Code: "

я попробовал ввести реальные данные, и все в порядке. переадресовывает на paypal.

Посмотрел что выдает массив $resArray. Если реальные данные, то все в порядке:

> Array ( [TOKEN] => EC-2FP9406707909490N [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-01-27T14:52:37Z [CORRELATIONID] => b6329a695bbf3 [ACK] => Success [VERSION] => 93 [BUILD] => 18308778 )

```
   $resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
    } 
    else  
    {
        $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
        $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
        $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
        $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

        echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
        echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
        echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
        echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
        echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
    }
```

Если меняю на данные sandbox (а они точно верные) $resArray возвращается пустой.

> Array ( ) SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message:
>   Short Error Message: Error Code: Error Severity Code:

В чем может быть проблема? Я не делал никаких изменений, все файлы оригинальные с офф. страницы.. Ведь если что то не правильно в коде, то и реальная оплата бы не работала...

скачал и заинсталил opencart cms. в нем интегрирован модуль express checkout. ввел реальные данные - работает. ввел данные sandbox - то же не работает! посмотрел в дебугере вот какие ошибки выдает:

```
2016-01-27 18:27:41 - PayPal Express debug (Call data): {"METHOD":"SetExpressCheckout","MAXAMT":"132.50","RETURNURL":"http:\/\/comps.lt\/oc156\/index.php?route=payment\/pp_express\/checkoutReturn","CANCELURL":"http:\/\/comps.lt\/oc156\/index.php?route=checkout\/checkout","REQCONFIRMSHIPPING":0,"NOSHIPPING":1,"LOCALECODE":"EN","LANDINGPAGE":"Login","HDRIMG":null,"HDRBORDERCOLOR":"","HDRBACKCOLOR":"","PAYFLOWCOLOR":"","CHANNELTYPE":"Merchant","ALLOWNOTE":"0","PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT":"","PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE":"USD","PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION":"Sale","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0":false,"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0":"iPhone","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0":"product 11","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0":"101.00","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0":1,"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL0":"http:\/\/comps.lt\/oc156\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=40","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0":"10.00","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTUNIT0":"kg","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1":"shipping","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1":"Flat Shipping Rate","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1":"5.00","L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1":1,"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT":"106.00","PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT":"106.00"}
2016-01-27 18:27:42 - PayPal Express debug (cURL failed): {"error":"SSL connect error","errno":35}
2016-01-27 18:27:42 - PayPal Express debug (Result): false
2016-01-27 18:27:42 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/comps/domains/comps.lt/public_html/oc156/catalog/model/payment/pp_express.php on line 10
2016-01-27 18:27:42 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: L_LONGMESSAGE0 in /home/comps/domains/comps.lt/public_html/oc156/catalog/controller/payment/pp_express.php on line 1302
```

как я понимаю как и в моем скрипте запаривается на ТОКЕНЕ... значит все же в paypal проблема? может какие то изменения были о которых я не знаю? :(

Comment: А Вы в paypal sandbox залогинены? Я могу ошибаться, но по-моему, чтобы paypal sandbox работал, надо иметь открытую сессию в https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Comment: залогился везде где только можно. не помогло. решил все же что что то не так в моем коде. скачал и заинсталил opencart cms. в нем интегрирован модуль express checkout. ввел реальные данные - работает. ввел данные sandbox - то же не работает! посмотрел в дебугере вот какие ошибки выдает: (добавил в главный пост) как я понимаю как и в моем скрипте запаривается на ТОКЕНЕ

Comment: в sandbox и в paypal разные аккаунты, вы заходите под нужным аккаунтом в sandbox?